# Ошибка Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: SettingsActivity cannot be cast to android.app.Activity

Tags: java, android

Падает приложение при попытке зайти в настойки.
часть MainActivity.java:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuItem mi = menu.add(0, 1, 0, R.string.pref);
        mi.setIntent(new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class));
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
      }
```

SettingsActivity.java:

```
package ru.devgor.gorlovka;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceFragment;

public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceFragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) throws ClassCastException  {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref);
    }
}
```

pref.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<CheckBoxPreference
 android:key="chb"
 android:title="Wifi при выходе" android:summaryOn="При выходе wifi будет выключаться" android:summaryOff="При выходе wifi не будет выключаться">
</CheckBoxPreference>
<CheckBoxPreference android:key="chb1" android:title="Wifi при входе" android:summaryOn="При входе wifi будет включаться" android:summaryOff="При входе wifi не будет включаться"/>
<CheckBoxPreference android:key="chb2" android:title="Загрузка картинок" android:summaryOn="При быстром интернете" android:summaryOff="При мобильном интернете"/>

<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:title="Первая кнопка">
    <EditTextPreference android:key="btn11" android:dialogTitle="Название" android:dialogMessage="Введите название первой кнопки"/>
    <EditTextPreference android:key="btn12" android:dialogTitle="Ссылка" android:dialogMessage="Введите ссылку, на которую следует перейти"/>
</PreferenceScreen>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Comment: У вас SettingsActivity  - фрагмент.

Answer (score 1):

Как верно заметил @Suvitruf, вы пытаетесь запустить активити, но ваш класс, коий вы передаёте в конструктор `Intent`-а - наследуется от `PreferenceFragment`.

Об этом и говорит вам `ClassCastException`.

Comment: И как это исправить?

Comment: @ВладГлушко, смотря чего вы в итоге хотите... Но запускать надо таким образом только Activity. Засим вам надо или сделать новую активити и в ней запустить ваш фрагмент или вместо запуска новой активити добавить фрагмент в текущую.